# parsing JSON not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I have following valid JSON to Parse:

```
[{"name":"kkkk","empid":"55628","address":"mumbai","mobile":"9525878558"},{"name":"xtreme","empid":"20","address":"stripes","mobile":"9999597"},{"name":"xtreme","empid":"20","address":"stripes","mobile":"9699597"},{"name":"xtreme","empid":"20","address":"stripes","mobile":"9699597"},{"name":"xtreme","empid":"20","address":"stripes","mobile":"9699597"},{"name":"xtreme","empid":"20","address":"stripes","mobile":"9689597"},{"name":"xtreme","empid":"20","address":"stripes","mobile":"9699597"},{"name":"xtreme","empid":"20","address":"stripes","mobile":"9689597"},{"name":"xtreme","empid":"20","address":"stripes","mobile":"9699597"},{"name":"vx","empid":"96","address":"addre","mobile":"9999596"},{"name":"vxx","empid":"96","address":"addre","mobile":"96899"},{"name":"vx","empid":"96","address":"addre","mobile":"9689596"}]
```

After parsing this I want to set its property on the employee object. I have tried following code which is not working:

```
NSDictionary *dict=[parser objectWithString:firstParseData];
NSString *secondParseData=[dict objectForKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@"name=%@",secondParseData);
```

I dont understand what is the problem please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `firstParseData` is the json you provided, then you will get the `NSArray` in `dict` variable, not the `NSDictionary`.

If you need all of the names use `valueForKey:` method for that array. It will return the array of all the names in `dict` variable.

If you need only one name - use `objectAtIndex:` and `valueForKey:` on returned object to get name value on given index of top-level array.